# ERROR AL EJECUTAR PROCEDIMIENTO ALMACENADO EN JAVA

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedure, insert

Hola tengo el siguiente codigo en lenguaje java, requiero agregar datos al ingresar un empleado, al momento de ejecutar la aplicacion me dice QUE NO SE ENCUENTRA EL PROCEDIMIENTO ALMACENADO 'INSERTAR_EMPLEADOS'.
Ya verifique y no encuentro algun error , el nombre del sp es correcto y de igual forma la cantidad de campos es la misma.
Alguien que me pueda ayudar a resolver este error.

```
String getRuta = ruta.getText();
            FileInputStream fis = null;

            try {
                File file = new File(getRuta);
                int Verificar = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "DESEA GUARDAR LOS DATOS DEL EMPLEADO ?", "PREGUNTA", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if (Verificar == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

                    try (
                            PreparedStatement consulta = ConexionSQL.Conexion.conn.prepareStatement("{call INSERTAR_EMPLEADOS (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}")) {
                        consulta.setBinaryStream(1, fis, (int) file.length());
                        consulta.setString(2, AddEmpleado.NOMBRE.getText());
                        consulta.setString(3, edad.getText());
                        consulta.setString(4, AddEmpleado.Hombre_Mujer.toString());
                        consulta.setString(5, AddEmpleado.CURP.getText());
                        consulta.setString(6, AddEmpleado.RFC.getText());
                        consulta.setString(7, NSS.getText());
                        consulta.setString(8, AddEmpleado.estado_civil.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        consulta.setString(9, AddEmpleado.escolaridad.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        consulta.setString(10, AddEmpleado.celular.getText());
                        consulta.setString(11, AddEmpleado.telcasa.getText());
                        consulta.setString(12, AddEmpleado.email.getText());
                        consulta.setString(13, CP.getText());
                        consulta.setString(14, AddEmpleado.CALLE.getText());
                        consulta.setString(15, AddEmpleado.localidad.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        consulta.setString(16, AddEmpleado.municipio.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        consulta.setString(17, AddEmpleado.estados.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        consulta.setString(18, ((JTextField) AddEmpleado.fecha.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());

                        ResultSet rs = consulta.executeQuery();
                        String respuesta = "";
                        while (rs.next()) {
                            respuesta = rs.getString(1).toString();
                        }
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, respuesta, "CONFIRMACION", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        Limpiar();
                    }

                }
            

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR AL REGISTRAR " + e.getMessage(), "ERROR", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, img);

            } finally {
                try {
                    fis.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "OCURRIO UN ERROR AL CERRAR LA CONEXION" + ex.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, img);

                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: para ver la traza completa de error coloca `e.printStackTrace();` en el catch, y después actualizas la pregunta con la traza del error.

Answer (score 0):

en la linea donde defines el procedimiento a ejecutar y  para el caso muy particular de
Oracle 11g (si es el caso) debes colocar el esquema donde se encuentra dicho procedimiento.

Ejemplo :

> PreparedStatement consulta = ConexionSQL.Conexion.conn.prepareStatement("{call
> ESQUEMA.INSERTAR_EMPLEADOS (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}")) {

esto se debe a que el esquema no tiene sinónimos definidos.